# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzrx;

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, google-play-services, shopify

I'm creating an Shopify Android App using their api. My app also use Google firebase to do the sign-ins. this is my dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.shopify.mobilebuysdk:buy:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
}
```

When I try to build the app I'm getting this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzrx;

I tried to add this on my build.gradle(app):

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

So then a got this:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzrx.class

What can I do to use both libraries in the same project?

Comment: This solve my problem:   

configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-wallet'
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

I Just solved my problem with this lines:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-wallet'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this, might help in build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
```

Comment: I do not have success yet.